# react throws type error for undefined object before ternary can check if object is undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, reactjs, undefined

LONG STORY SHORT: I would like for it to load the object in the nested array IF it is not equal to undefined but react throws typeError

I have this component that takes props from a parent component. Essentially I have an array that contains chat information and when I try to access it in this child component I get some very strange behaviour.

for example if I console log(props.conversations) I get my array which looks like this: conversations[{host, members[{ username }], log[{ author, content, timestamp }]}].

if I console log (props.conversations[0]) ill get the first object in that array. But if I console log (props.conversations[0].log) I get undefined. And thats fine because at the start the state will not be defined or contain anything, so I put a ternary operator as shown below in the code  props.conversations[props.index].log[0] == null ?
but all i get is TypeError: Cannot read property 'log' of undefined at the ternary function.

Maybe I am not understanding this correctly or maybe it how react functions?
Again I would like for it to load the object in the nested array IF it is not equal to undefined.

Highly appreciate the help. The most important part is the friends component. I only show the other ones to show the state being passed down.

```
function Friends(props) {

console.log(props.conversations[props.index]);

return (
    <div className="friend">
        <img className="friendavatar" src={require("./static/bobby.jpg")}></img>
        <div className="friendname">{props.username}</div>
        <span className="iswatchingtitle"> is watching <strong>{props.watching}</strong></span>
        <div className="friendchat" onClick={props.togglechat}>
           {props.conversations[props.index].log[0] == null ?
            <div>undefined</div>
            :
            <div>defined!</div>
           }
        </div>
    </div>
)
}
```

social component

```
function Social(props) {

return (
    <div>
        <div className="userquickdash row">
            <div className="usernamedash">{props.username}</div>
            <div className="logout"><a href="/users/logout" onClick={props.fetchlogout}>logout</a></div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <form className="search-form-flex" method="GET" action="/search">
                <input className="user-search" id="search" type="search" placeholder=" Search users..." name="usersearch"></input>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div className='friendchatcontainer' refs='friendchatcontainer'>
            {/* Append friends from social bar state (props.friends). For each friend return appropriate object info to build Friends div using Friends(props) function above. */}
            {props.friends.map(function(friend, index) {
                // Shortens length of video title if length of string is over 48.
                let friendWatching = function friendWatchingLengthSubstring() {
                    if (friend.watching.length > 57) {
                        let friendWatching = friend.watching.substring(0, 54) + '...';
                        return friendWatching;
                    } else {
                        friendWatching = friend.watching;
                        return friendWatching;
                    }
                };

                return (
                    <Friends username={friend.username}
                    watching={friendWatching()}
                    key={index}
                    index={index}
                    togglechat={props.togglechat}
                    conversations={props.conversations}
                    />
                )
            })}
        </div>
    </div>
)
}
```

socialbar component

```
class Socialbar extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);


    this.state = { isLoggedIn: (cookies.get('loggedIn')), 
                  sidebarximgSrc: sidebarcloseimg, 
                  sidebarStatus: 'open', 
                  username: cookies.get('loggedIn'),
                  friends: friends,
                  users: {},
                  conversations: [],
                 };


}

// function to run when mongodb gets information that state has changed.
// test if the current state is equal to new object array.
// then do something.
appendFriends() {

}

componentDidMount() {
   if (this.state.sidebarStatus === 'open') {
       document.getElementsByClassName('maindash')[0].classList.add('maindashwide');
       this.openSideBar();
   } else {
       document.getElementsByClassName('maindash')[0].classList.remove('maindashwide');
       this.closeSideBar();
   }
    // check for user logged in cookie, if true fetch users.
    if (this.state.isLoggedIn) {
        this.fetchUsers();
    }

    this.getFriendConversations();
};

getFriendConversations() {
    // build loop function that updates state for conversations based on length of friends array in state. 
    var conversationsArray = this.state.conversations;

    for (var i = 0; i < friends.length; i++) {


    console.log(aconversationbetweenfriends[i]);
    conversationsArray.push(aconversationbetweenfriends[i]);
}

this.setState({conversations: conversationsArray});
}

render() {
    let sidebar;

    const isLoggedIn = this.state.isLoggedIn;
    if (!isLoggedIn) {
        sidebar = <Login />
    } else {
        sidebar = <Social username={this.state.username} friends={this.state.friends} fetchlogout={this.fetchlogout} togglechat={this.togglechat} conversations={this.state.conversations}  />
    }

 return (
        <div>
            <div className="sidebar sidebar-open" ref="sidebar">
                <div className="sidebarcontainer">
                    {sidebar}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="sidebarx sidebarxopen" ref="sidebarx" onClick={this.toggleSideBar}>
                <img className="sidebaropenimg" src={this.state.sidebarximgSrc} ref='sidebarximg'></img>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
} 
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a good idea to access the element directly before validation.

Use something like this:

```
props.conversations[props.index] && props.conversations[props.index].log[0]
```

Tip: User object destructuring and default props.

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare for undefined like this :

```
{props.conversations[props.index].log[0] === undefined ?
        <div>undefined</div>
        :
        <div>defined!</div>
       }
```

Also, You can go to below link for sandbox running example.

[Sandbox link for example to show how you should check for undefined](https://codesandbox.io/s/l7q9zvk597)

Answer (score 0):

Hi first of all check your {props.index} print this value. if it is proper then try this out.

```
 {
       props.conversations[props.index] ?
        props.conversations[props.index].log[0] ? <div>defined!</div>:<div>Undefined</div> 
       : 
        <div>Undefined</div>
  }
```

This will check if props.conversations[props.index] is defined then and then only try to process props.conversations[props.index].log[0]. So you will not get TypeError: Cannot read property 'log' of undefined at the ternary function.

Comment: thankyou, i was so confused as to why it wasnt accessing the nested object. I was thinking throughout the day aswell and i realized this might be a situation where i should be using propTypes.isRequired. Either way thanks.